# html output issue with special characters - m2

Tags: magento2, category-description, special-character

```
<li> �" solid hardwood front </li><li> �"
```

Frontend side showing like this. how can I show proper output in the browser?

**Original text**: `<li> 3/4" solid hardwood front </li>`

I have tried these bellow functions after that ul li is showing good but still issue with special characters.

**html_entity_decode(htmlentities(utf8_decode(strip_tags($description))));**

**html_entity_decode**

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inject this code in your block and pass your content in function :

```
/**
 * @var \Magento\Cms\Model\Template\FilterProvider
 */
protected $_filterProvider;
/**
 * @var \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface
 */
protected $_storeManager;
/**
 * @param \Magento\Cms\Model\Template\FilterProvider $filterProvider
 * @param \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager
 */
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Cms\Model\Template\FilterProvider $filterProvider,
    \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager
) {
    $this->_filterProvider = $filterProvider;
    $this->_storeManager = $storeManager;
}
/**
 * Static block $content
 */
public function getContentFromStaticBlock($content)
{
    $storeId = $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getId();
    return $this->_filterProvider->getBlockFilter()->setStoreId($storeId)->filter($content);
}
```

Call this function **getContentFromStaticBlock()** and pass value as argument.

Comment: Thanks,, Ir's Working .

Answer (score 1):

Try using below code in your content:

**Your Original Text:** `<li> 3/4" solid hardwood front </li>`

**Chnage it to:** `<li> &frac34;" solid hardwood front </li>`

Instead of using `3/4`, use HTML code **`&frac34;`** in your code.

This will give output as below:

[image]

Hope this will help you!!!